# Parsing table with beautiful soup returns nonetype object

Tags: html, datatable, beautifulsoup

I have attempted multiple times to parse the table labeled earn_calendar_tbl with the class id of mp_lightborder dataTable no-footer in the url given in the code.

Is this table impossible to parse?

```
url = 'https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings?d=20190712'
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
table = soup.find("table",{"id":"earn_calendar_tbl"})
rows = table.find_all("tr")'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page does a POST request which receives the data as json response. See which items (likely the empty value key value pairs) can be removed. I have commented out those definitely not needed for this request but you might want for later - save you typing out. You can find this POST request in the network tab when clicking show all for results.

```
import requests

body ={
'draw':4,
'columns[0][data]':'Details.Symbol',
#'columns[0][name]' : '',
'columns[0][searchable]': True,
'columns[0][orderable]': True,
#'columns[0][search][value]' : '',
'columns[0][search][regex]':False,
'columns[1][data]':'Details.CompanyName',
#'columns[1][name]' : '',
'columns[1][searchable]': True,
'columns[1][orderable]':True,
#'columns[1][search][value]' : '',
'columns[1][search][regex]':False,
'columns[2][data]':'Details.EarnDate',
#'columns[2][name]' : '',
'columns[2][searchable]':True,
'columns[2][orderable]': True,
#'columns[2][search][value]':'',
'columns[2][search][regex]':False,
'columns[3][data]':'Details.TimeOfDayValue',
'columns[3][name]':'TimeOfDayValue',
'columns[3][searchable]':True,
'columns[3][orderable]':True,
'columns[3][search][value]': '0 to 1', #
'columns[3][search][regex]':False,
'columns[4][data]':'Details.ReportedPRValue',
#'columns[4][name]' : '',
'columns[4][searchable]': True,
'columns[4][orderable]':True,
#'columns[4][search][value]' :'',
'columns[4][search][regex]': False,
'columns[5][data]':'Details.ConfCallStr',
#'columns[5][name]' : '',
'columns[5][searchable]': True,
'columns[5][orderable]':True,
#'columns[5][search][value]': '',
'columns[5][search][regex]': False,
'columns[6][data]':'Details.PrevEarnEffectValue',
#'columns[6][name]' : '',
'columns[6][searchable]': True,
'columns[6][orderable]':True,
#'columns[6][search][value]': '',
'columns[6][search][regex]':False,
'columns[7][data]':'Details.IVStraddleValue',
#'columns[7][name]' : '',
'columns[7][searchable]': True,
'columns[7][orderable]':True,
#'columns[7][search][value]': '',
'columns[7][search][regex]':False,
'columns[8][data]':'Details.ThisEarnEffectValue',
#'columns[8][name]' : '',
'columns[8][searchable]': True,
'columns[8][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[8][search][value]': '',
'columns[8][search][regex]':False,
'columns[9][data]':'Details.OptVolumeTotal',
#'columns[9][name]' : '',
'columns[9][searchable]': True,
'columns[9][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[9][search][value]': '',
'columns[9][search][regex]':False,
'columns[10][data]':'Details.MarketCapTotal',
#'columns[10][name]' : '',
'columns[10][searchable]': True,
'columns[10][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[10][search][value]' : '',
'columns[10][search][regex]':False,
'columns[11][data]':'Details.AvgOptVolume',
'columns[11][name]':'AvgOptVolume',
'columns[11][searchable]': True,
'columns[11][orderable]': True,
#    'columns[11][search][value]' : '',
'columns[11][search][regex]' : False,
'columns[12][data]':'Stats_Last4.AbsAvgMove',
'columns[12][name]':'Last4_AbsAvg',
'columns[12][searchable]':True,
'columns[12][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[12][search][value]' : '',
'columns[12][search][regex]':False,
'columns[13][data]':'Stats_Last4.AbsMinMove',
'columns[13][name]':'Last4_AbsMin',
'columns[13][searchable]':True,
'columns[13][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[13][search][value]': '',
'columns[13][search][regex]': False,
'columns[14][data]':'Stats_Last4.AbsMaxMove',
'columns[14][name]':'Last4_AbsMax',
'columns[14][searchable]':True,
'columns[14][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[14][search][value]' : '',
'columns[14][search][regex]': False,
'columns[15][data]':'Details.IVStraddleValue',
'columns[15][name]':'Last4_Expected',
'columns[15][searchable]':True,
'columns[15][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[15][search][value]': '',
'columns[15][search][regex]': False,
'columns[16][data]':'Stats_Last4.RelativeValue',
'columns[16][name]':'Last4_Relative',
'columns[16][searchable]':True,
'columns[16][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[16][search][value]': '',
'columns[16][search][regex]':False,
'columns[17][data]':'Stats_Last12.AbsAvgMove',
'columns[17][name]':'Last12_AbsAvg',
'columns[17][searchable]':True,
'columns[17][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[17][search][value]': '',
'columns[17][search][regex]': False,
'columns[18][data]':'Stats_Last12.AbsMinMove',
'columns[18][name]':'Last12_AbsMin',
'columns[18][searchable]': True,
'columns[18][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[18][search][value]': '',
'columns[18][search][regex]':False,
'columns[19][data]':'Stats_Last12.AbsMaxMove',
'columns[19][name]':'Last12_AbsMax',
'columns[19][searchable]':True,
'columns[19][orderable]':True,
#    'columns[19][search][value]': '',
'columns[19][search][regex]': False,
'columns[20][data]':'Details.IVStraddleValue',
'columns[20][name]':'Last12_Expected',
'columns[20][searchable]':True,
'columns[20][orderable]':True,
#'columns[20][search][value]': '',
'columns[20][search][regex]':False,
'columns[21][data]':'Stats_Last12.RelativeValue',
'columns[21][name]':'Last12_Relative',
'columns[21][searchable]':True,
'columns[21][orderable]':True,
#'columns[21][search][value]': '',
'columns[21][search][regex]': False,
'columns[22][data]':'Details.ConfirmationTypeMulti',
'columns[22][name]':'ConfirmationTypeMulti',
'columns[22][search][value]':'Announced',
'columns[22][searchable]':True,
'columns[22][orderable]':True,
#'columns[22][search][value]': '',
'columns[22][search][regex]':False,
'columns[23][data]':'Details.StockTypeMulti',
'columns[23][name]':'StockTypeMulti',
'columns[23][searchable]':True,
'columns[23][orderable]':True,
#'columns[23][search][value]':'',
'columns[23][search][regex]':False,
'columns[24][data]':'Details.HasOptions',
'columns[24][name]':'HasOptions',
'columns[24][searchable]':True,
'columns[24][orderable]': True,
'columns[24][search][value]':'',
'columns[24][search][regex]': False,
'columns[25][data]':'InWatchlist',
'columns[25][name]':'InWatchlist',
'columns[25][searchable]':True,
'columns[25][orderable]':True,
#'columns[25][search][value]':'',
'columns[25][search][regex]':False,
'columns[26][data]':'Details.CurrentStockPrice',
'columns[26][name]':'CurrentStockPrice',
'columns[26][searchable]':True,
'columns[26][orderable]':True,
'columns[26][search][regex]': False,
'order[0][column]':10,
'order[0][dir]':'desc',
'start':0,
'length': -1,
'search[value]':'',
'search[regex]':False}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r =  s.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Earnings?d=20190712')
    r = s.post('https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/EarningsInnerData?d=20190712', data = body).json()
```

Comment: What is the name "body" referring to?

Comment: everything between the {} basically the fields for the form. Provides the filters. Possible you can remove the True, False lines as well - though play with it and see.